# Выставление прав для Nginx upload module

Tags: nginx

Возникла проблема с правами

> upload_store_access user:rw group:rwall:rw

как разрешить также выполнение ?

> upload_store_access user:rwx group:rwxall:rwx

не работает и при попытке запуска nginx дает

> invalid value "user:rwx" in/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:67

Помогите, пожалуйста, не пойму, как правильно указать права?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанная вами строка правильна согласно синтаксису Nginx. То есть вполне возможно записать так

```
upload_store_access user:rw group:rw all:rw;
```

Насколько я понимаю (стоит уточнить в группе Nginx), для временных файлов запрещается выставление прав на исполнение, то есть только r и w допускаются.

Плюс обратите внимание: директива указывается внутри секций server и location и на конце точка с запятой.

Comment: Да я уточнил уже. rw не больше. :) точку с запятой ставил конечно, просто не указал когда цитировал.